# android listview with search inside SlidingDrawer

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

I am developing an application in android where I use a SlidingDrawer with a listView.
The problem is that I want to add a textBox on the top in order to filter the content of the list.
I generate a separate application with that layout (listView with a textbox on the top) and runs OK. When I copy the code from that application to the one with the SlidingDrawer, the listView does not apears, only apears the textbox.

Code of the layout:

```
<SlidingDrawer android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:handle="@+id/handle"
        android:content="@+id/content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView android:id="@id/handle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/tabcerrado2"/>

        <LinearLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:background="#C0C0C0">

                <EditText android:id="@+id/Texto"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="">
                </EditText>
                <ListView android:id="@+id/ListView01"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
</SlidingDrawer>
```

Answer (score 1):

I only had to set the orientation of the LinearLayout as vertical and the problem solved.